# XGBoost get predict_contrib using sklearn API?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

In Python, XGBoost allows you to train/predict using their Booster class or using their sklearn API (http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html). I'm using the sklearn API, and want to use the `pred_contribs` capabilities of XGBoost. I would expect this to work, but it doesn't:

```
model = xgb.XGBClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = model.predict_proba(X_test, pred_contribs=True)
```

It looks like `pred_contribs` is only a parameter for the `Booster` class predict function. How do I use this parameter through the sklearn API? Or is there an easy workaround to get the prediction contributors after training using the sklearn API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `get_booster()` method from XGBClassifier, which will return a Booster object, after the XGBClassifier has been fitted with training data.

After that you can simply call `predict()` on the Booster object with `pred_contribs = True`.

Example code:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier, DMatrix
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris_data = load_iris()

# Taking only first 100 samples to make this a binary problem, 
# else it will be multi-class and shape of pred_contribs will change
X, y = iris_data.data[:100], iris_data.target[:100]

# This data has 4 features
print(X.shape)
Output: (100, 4)


clf = XGBClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)

# This is what you need
booster = clf.get_booster()


# Using only a single sample for predict, you can use multiple
test_X = [X[0]]

# Wrapping the test X into a DMatrix, need by Booster
predictions = booster.predict(DMatrix(test_X), pred_contribs=True)

print(predictions.shape)

# Output has 5 columns, 1 for each feature, and last for bias
Output: (1, 5)
```

Comment: Hey! But get.booster().predict gives out continous data even though the classifier take in binary y_test. How to avoid that problem?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer are you trying to predict the class? The solution here is for something else. For predicting the class, just use `clf.predict()`. Why are you trying to get booster ?

Comment: clf.predict() gives out prediction of entire classifier, I wanted to get from each tree in XGB.  in Random Forest you just do clf[0].predict -> for the first tree, but here it doesn't work. With booster I got all the trees. Maybe I am getting it wrong.

Comment: Nvm I understand now how stupid this would be.